# Alter content of search api views

Tags: views

I've used drupal7, Search API 7.x-1.16, Search views 7.x-1.16, Solr search
7.x-1.9, Apache Solr search
7.x-1.7.

I am listing contents of some content type. Now i want to trim description field only if the content belongs to some content type. 
How to do this using **theme_preprocess_views_view_fields**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you want to use the ***theme_preprocess_views_view_fields*** hook?

Why not add the attribute **Content: type** to your View fields (see image), and then check the content type within a View template:

[image]

Then your code in ***views-view-fields--[my_view]--[my_display].tpl.php*** could look something like this:

```
<?php 
  //check content type
  if($fields['content_type']->content == 'My content type') {      
    //trim description by 200 chars (respecting full words)
    $pos = strpos($fields['field_my_description]->content, ' ', 200);
    substr($fields['field_my_description]->content, 0, $pos); 
  }
?>

<h3><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></h3>
<div class="my-description">
  <?php print $fields['field_my_description']->content; ?>
</div>
```

I haven't tested or tried the above code, but the proof of concept should be enough to help you along.

Using a Views template instead of a hook is also easier for site builders / themers to debug or change.